# Writing byte array to a file folder

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

I want to write a byte array to a **folder**. The byte array is created by converting a zip file to byte array and when I convert it back I want to write the file it in the unzipped(extracted) format.

My code is as below. In the line

```
FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

**Access Denied exception** is throwing. I want to write the byte array content directly to a folder in unzipped format. Is there any way I can do it directly rather than writing the byte array in zipped format and then unzipping it?

```
private void (byte[] content, String baseFolder) {

    File f = new File(baseFolder,"TestFolder");

    if (!f.isDirectory()) 
        f.mkdirs();
    if (!f.canWrite()) 
        f.setWritable(true);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fileOuputStream.write(content);
        fileOuputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html

You can read in the zip file with ZipInputStream and write all the files into that folder.